# Projection onto $\ell^{2,1}$ ball

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, calculus-of-variations, convex-optimization

Does anyone have an idea how to project onto the $\ell^{2,1}$ ball efficiently, i.e. how to solve
$$ u = \arg \min_u  \|u-f \|^2    \text{such that } \left(\sum_i \big(\sum_j |u_{i,j}|\big)^2 \right)^{1/2} \leq 1$$
for a matrix $u \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ efficiently?

Comment: One approach is described in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.2631.pdf (Theorem 5 and 6).

Comment: Hi Christian and thanks for the reply. Unfotunately, there exist different definitions of $\ell^{p,q}$ norms in literature. The unit ball I would like to project on would be the $\ell^{1,2}$ ball in the notation of the paper you mentioned. In my problem the $\ell^2$ norm is 'outside' and the $\ell^1$ norm is 'inside'. The paper seems to deals with the problem where the order is reversed.

Comment: Thanks! I am currently using a splitting method (ADMM) by rewriting the problem using several variables along with linear constraints. This way each subproblem in the ADMM algorithm is fairly easy to solve. However, it would be great if there was a faster way than my current ADMM scheme...

Comment: OK, that's pretty much the direction I was thinking: Introduce the inner norm as an independent variable (say $c$) depending on $i$ only, and add the constraint $\|c\|_2^2 \leq 1$ (since you minimize over $c$, you can replace the equality constraint with $\|u_{i,\cdot}\|_1 \leq c_i$). If ADMM is not fast enough, you might want to look at extrapolated splitting schemes such as (preconditioned) Douglas-Rachford.

Comment: By the way, if you already have an approach you would like to improve, *please* say so and describe it (briefly) in the question. That would have saved me quite a bit of time. (I assume this is what the downvotes were for.)

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. I just came up and implemented the ADMM idea. Since some of these projections (particularly involving 1 and 2 norms) have closed form solutions or reduce to very simple problems, I was wondering if this is the case here, too. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Since the projection on to the $\ell_{1,2}$ ball doesn't have a simple solution, I would be surprised if there is one for the $\ell_{2,1}$ ball. The difficulty is that this case involves the *squared* $\ell_1$ norm rather than the simple $\ell_2$ norm. Maybe the following can be helpful if you would like to avoid splitting the problem.

First, note that your constraint can be equivalently expressed as 
$$ \|u\|_{2,1}^2 = \sum_i \|u_{i}\|_1^2 \leq 1,$$
where $u_i$ is the $i$th row of $u$.
Introducing a Lagrange multiplier $\lambda\geq 0$, the metric projection problem can be formulated as
$$\min_{u}\sup_\lambda \frac12\|u-f\|_{2,2}^2 + \lambda (\|u\|_{2,1}^2 -1).$$
Assume now that $\|f\|_{2,1}>1$ (otherwise we would have $u=f$), hence we can assume that for the minimizers $\|u\|_{2,1} = 1$ (the necessary optimality with respect to $\lambda$) and $\lambda >0$ holds (needs to be shown using a proof by contradiction, see below).
For optimality with respect to $u$, first note that the reformulated minimization problem completely decouples for the $u_i$. Hence, for every $i$, we have the optimality condition 
$$0\in \partial\left(\frac12\|u_i-f_i\|_2^2 + \lambda \|u_i\|_1^2\right).$$
Applying a sum rule ($0$ is a regular point), this is equivalent with
$$\frac1\lambda (f_i -u_i) \in \partial(\|\cdot\|_1^2)(u_i) = 2 \|u_i\|_1 \partial(\|\cdot\|_1)(u_i)$$
(using the fact that the subdifferential of one-half of the squared norm is the duality mapping, see Schirotzek, *Nonsmooth Analysis*, Remark 4.6.3).
If $f_i\neq 0$, then $\|u_i\|_1\neq 0$ (otherwise we obtain a contradiction).
Now we use the equivalence for every $\gamma>0$
$$-p\in\partial F(u) \Leftrightarrow u = \mathrm{prox}_{\gamma F}(u-\gamma p),$$
where the proximal mapping for the $1$-norm is the *soft-thresholding operator*
$$\mathrm{prox}_{\gamma\|\cdot\|_1}(w) = S_\gamma(w) = (|w|-\gamma)^+\mathrm{sign}(w)$$
with $(w)^+ = \max\{0,w\}$ (all of which is to be understood componentwise if $w$ is a vector).
Setting $\gamma = 2\lambda \|u_i\|_1$, we thus obtain the relations
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
&u_i = (|f_i|-2\lambda \|u_i\|_1)^+\mathrm{sign}(f_i) \qquad \text{for all }i,\\
&\sum_i \|u_i\|_1^2 = 1.
\end{aligned}
$$
(Here you get the desired contradiction: if $\lambda =0$, then $u_i = f_i$, which violates the second condition.)

Inserting the first relations into the second, you can solve for given $u_i$ for $\lambda$ via root finding, and for given $\lambda$, you can apply a fixed point iteration to (hopefully) compute $u_i$.